# POST image from Windows Phone 8 to PHP

Tags: php, image, windows-phone-7, post

I want to send image from windows phone 8 to PHP with post request.

In html:

```
<form action="reciever.php" metod="post">
<input type="file" name="media"/>
</form>
```

And recive result as:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['media']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['media']['tmp_name']))
{
$name = $_FILES['media']['name'];
$source = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
}
```

But when i send Base64 encoded image form phone. He did't recognize it as $_FILES.

So how send WP8 image and handle it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Unless WP8 is utterly insane, you will need to specify an enctype on the form to allow file uploads:

```
<form action="receiver.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also note that you typoed `metod`, so possibly the form is submitting as a GET. And your file validation logic needs work as well. Don't do ANYTHING with the $_FILES data until you've checked for errors:

```
if ($_FILES['media']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['media']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: That is problem. Data sended from WP8 doesn't recognize as $_FILES in PHP for some reason